# Multioutput Stacking Regressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn

One-shot question: I'm trying to build a Multiputput Stacked Regressor (added to sklearn 0.22). 
As far I understand, I have to combine `StackingRegressor` and `MultiOutputRegressor`. After several attemps this seems to be the right order:

```
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import OrthogonalMatchingPursuit
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingRegressor
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.svm import SVR

estimators = [  ('svr', SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)),  
        ('knn',KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=5)),
        ('omp', OrthogonalMatchingPursuit())
         ]

reg = MultiOutputRegressor(StackingRegressor( estimators = estimators, final_estimator= RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=5)))
X=np.random.random((200,20))
y = np.random.random((200,4))
reg.fit(X,y)

reg.predict(X)
```

But the `predict` method ends with an error

```
*** ValueError: The base estimator should implement a predict method
```

I searched such error in the sklean files and it seems related to the `MultiOutputRegressor`:

```
if not hasattr(self.estimator, "predict"):
    raise ValueError("The base estimator should implement a predict method")
```

So i tried to look at the `self.estimator` model:

```
reg.estimator.predict(X)
```

but I obtain this error:

```
*** AttributeError: 'StackingRegressor' object has no attribute 'final_estimator_'
```

Looking at the attributes of `reg.estimator`  I can not find `final_estimator_` but only `final_estimator` so my solution is to create such attribute:

```
reg.estimator.final_estimator_ = reg.estimator.final_estimator
```

It works but I'm not sure anymore if my model now is doing what it is suppose to do (maybe it is using the **same** final estimator for each coordinate of the output). 
Is this a bug due to the combination `StackingRegressor` + `MultiOutputRegressor` or I'm missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Judging by the error message *** AttributeError: 'StackingRegressor' object has no attribute 'final_estimator_' you have run your code with a syntactic mistake with 'final_estimator_=' instead of 'final_estimator='. Could you double check.

Comment: `reg.estimator.final_estimator_ = reg.estimator.final_estimator` was a workaround but I'm not sure it is the right thing to do...

Comment: Someone has opened an issue on Scikit-learn's github repo and it seems you are doing the right thing by creating the final_estimator_ attribute. It is also easy to check, by changing the number and/or type of the regressors - the predictions are different. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/16549

Comment: PERFECT: I will follow the discussion there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set stacking_method='predict' in Model Initialization, and it should work fine. Idk why the 'auto' option doesn't work, but quick fix like so:

```py
model = StackingClassifier(estimators=level0, final_estimator=level1, stack_method='predict', cv=5)
```